# How can one programmatically get the bundle constraint for an entity reference field?

Tags: views, entities, 9

I'm working in the context of a Views plugin. I have `$entity_type` and `$field`, as required in the snippet below. How can I get the bundle constraint for the entity reference field programmatically?

```
/** @var Drupal\field\Entity\FieldStorageConfig $field_configuration */
$field_configuration = FieldStorageConfig::loadByName($entity_type, $field);
```

`$field_configuration->getType()` gives me "entity_reference"

`$field_configuration->getSettings()['target_type']` gives me "taxonomy_term"

...but what methods return the vocabulary or vocabularies (bundles) that the entity reference field is set to be limited by (if at all) in its configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The types allowed by an entity reference field is stored in the field config (`FieldConfig.php` and the `field.field.*` yaml), not the field storage config (`FieldStorageConfig.php` and the `field.storage.*` yaml).

If you take a peek at one instance of a `field.field.*` yaml of an entity reference field, you'll see the `settings.handler_settings.target_bundle` property containing a list of allowed bundles for that entity reference field. To get this data from code, you'll need `FieldConfig::load(id)` or `FieldConfig::loadByName($entity_type_id, $bundle, $field_name)` depending on what data you have at hand. Once you get the field config instance, there is a `getSetting()` method which you can use to grab `handler_settings`.

Comment: This is helpful, but I think tells me I can't do what I want to do.